# How to make riped cloth?

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv, cloth-simulation

I'm new to blender and 3D in general. Im making this armor for an academic project.

[image]

The part betwen the legs is supposed to be a cloth like object, and i would like to make it look like old and a little ripped apart in the edges.. I dont realy know a way to do this, any advices on how to make this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, maybe show some pictures, I guess the solution depends on the level of detail and realism, because it could be modeling + material + even hair, etc...

Comment: You might try mapping the cloth and applying a texture with alpha where the rips would be, and you can get a lot of detail without modelling where it would be frayed around the edges etc. But like moonboots said there are different approaches depending on the level of realism you want to acheive.

Comment: Here is a few exaples what i would like to do:

https://www.pinterest.pt/pin/335799715973757665/

https://www.pinterest.pt/pin/335799715970884686/

https://www.pinterest.pt/pin/335799715965362927/

im focusing more in the ripped cloth part, i actualy found a tutorial, but its quite old and it didnt work for me =/

tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sbiuwaJ6PT4&t=806s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way. Assuming you are using a texture file like this with transparency (alpha) for the ripped texture.

[image]

Select the banner vertices on your model. In UV Editing: open your texture file with the ripped banner, <kbd>U</kbd> Unwrap, position your faces atop the image, Set this vertex group as a UV Map.

[image]

With our banner selected, in the shader editor set up a texture for our banner like this, add a new texture, <kbd>Shit</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to add nodes. Calling the image file with an Image Texture and specifying your UV Map in the UV Map or Texture Coordinate node. Don't forget to connect the alpha to make the ripped and tattered area transparent.

[image]

You'll probably want to add more geometry to the banner so it hangs more naturally. Note the banner in this method has no thickness only flat geometry.

Hope that helps.

Comment: yes, the drawback is that you can't add thickness to the cloth.

Comment: thanks that realy helped!!